# Any guidance regarding creation of folder for different density in android

Tags: android, xml, screen-density

I've created five folder for hdpi,mhdpi,xhdpi,xxhdpi,xxxhdpi,by using android srudio builtin option in these folder one file is working good on dofferent screen sizes but when I want to create new resource file in these folder that's not working what should I do.